# Captcha analysis question

Tags: c#, .net, captcha

I'm trying to solve automatically some capthas, but with no luck yet. Here are some examples:
[image: 332]
[image: 581]
[image: 763]

There are always only 3 numbers in black and white colors.

Can anyone help me with some links or point to examples with a similar type of captchas?
Are there any good .net libraries for image processing that could be useful for me?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** 
A lot of people already have asked why am I doing it. So I will answer here :)

My friend told that he would buy a case of beer to the person who will solve this task with a 25% accept rate. 
I want to know if I have chances :D

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the Amazon Mechanical Turk (god help us).

Comment: Voted to close, this is not the kind of question we want answers to here.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen i once had a thought to write captcha recognition application just for fun.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen i am another Andrey :)

Comment: I don't doubt that the topic is interesting, but actually getting a working answer here is not within the sites policy, or at least that's how I understand it. I daresay SOSI would be in a bit of pain if a site using a captcha could go here and find working code, or at least a dozen hints, on how to break theirs. I don't doubt there exists code that does it, but then why help out?

Comment: As someone who runs several forums and has to fight spambots far too often, I vote to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Captcha was introduced to stop applications like yours :-). If this is something legitimate then contact the website and see if they can provide you with an API. It is practically impossible to solve all the captchas even if you a very good algorithm. Even if your application starts solving these captchas what is the guarantee that the website will not block you from making multiple requests in short interval?

Comment: yeah, i know :) but it is still an interesting question for me :)

Comment: @Andrey unless you are a security researcher this isn't the type of question that brings about good feelings.